# Unable to import music from external HD into Audacity on Ubuntu

Tags: external-hdd, music, audacity

I am using Ubuntu version 20.04 and Cinnamon desktop. I am unable to import music from an external HD into Audacity. When I select "file - import" the external HD is not listed. I read another thread about this issue and it suggested that I go into Audacity permissions and select "allow import from external storage devices". I selected this and it did not solve the problem. The Audacity online manual and Audacity forums do not have anything on this issue. I can select the file box icon on the desktop and browse the entire contents of the external HD, and I can also open VLC media player and browse the entire contents of the music on the external HD.

Comment: Please clarify, are you using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS on which you added the cinnamon desktop? or using Ubuntu Cinnamon *remix* 20.04 ?

Comment: How did you install Audacity?

Comment: To:  not my real name.  I believe I installed Audacity from the command line- which is how I generally install all software.

Comment: How install may matter; if you if used `snap install` you'll have introduced a *snap* package which means it'll run *confined* by default, meaning it'll only have access to parts of your file-system; and not seeing external drives can be expected depending on details you've not provided (eg. where mounted & if you've enabled `removable-media` to allow it)